# chef: ERROR: ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

i'm getting this error while running `knife cookbook test` and i can't track it down. i've tried removing everything in all of the recipes and attributes.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem? It's okay to answer your own question. Please don't forget to mark an answer as correct! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is often the result of an error in your `metadata.rb` file for your cookbook. Particularly, check your `recipe` directives; you'll get this error if you omit the recipe description following the name.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error: it turned out that the error was caused by the name of a parameter, which was the same of a Ruby method. It was "name"; now it's "d_name" and error is gone ...

See also https://github.com/vpenso/debian-chef-cookbook/issues/1

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was that I was using a pretty old rubygems (1.4.1). Switching to the right gemset solved.